# Interacting with ASP.NET properties in Javascript

Tags: asp.net

I am try in to get the ClientID of one of my server controls to appear in a Javascript in my aspx page.

Obviously I am going about it the wrong way, but my intent should be made clear in the following:

```
doSomethingFirst();
var hid = "<% Response.Write(HidingField.ClientID) %>";
doSomethingElse(hid);
```

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: are you saying that this didn't work?  If you put in a Javascript alert and pass it hid after you set it what comes up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a bit of guessing about your intent, so forgive me if I've guessed wrong, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
doSomethingFirst();
var hid = document.getElementById('<%= HidingField.ClientID %>');
doSomethingElse(hid);
```

I assuming your intent is to get a reference to the DOM element represented by the client id so that you can then do some sort of javascript operation on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var hid = "<%= HidingField.ClientID %>";
```

making sure that "HidingField" is the ID of the server control?

Comment: `<% Response.Write(HidingField.ClientID) %>`'s kinda equivalent so I guess the OP has already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

It was the stupid missing semicolon.

I apologized for wasting everyone's time.